# ReactJS update UI or call method from different class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two classes, App and qrCode. The qrCode class returns a image of the qrcode based on the address provided in that classes state. The app class displays the qrcode component. In the method getSessionID, the app makes a request to the server, then should call updateQrCode to update the qrcode that is being shown.

How can I call the method updateQrCode from App.js? I can't instantiate a new QrCode, because that is not the instance that is being displayed.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import QrCode from "../qrCode/qrCode";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <QrCode />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getSessionID() {
    fetch("/getSessionID")
      .then((res) => {
        // code here to update the qr code in the instance of QrCode
        // QrCode.updateQrCode("test")
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data.message));
  }
}

export default App;
```

QrCode.js:

```
import "./qrCode.css";
import QRCode from "qrcode";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class QrCode extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      qrCode: {
        address: null,
        image: null,
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    generateQrCode(this.state.qrCode.address).then(
      function (image) {
        this.setState({
          qrCode: {
            address: this.state.qrCode.address,
            image: image,
          },
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  updateQrCode = () => {
    this.setState({
      qrCode: {
        address: "asdf",
        image: null,
      },
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.qrCode.image} alt="QR Code"></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function generateQrCode(address) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (address) {
      QRCode.toDataURL(address, {
        errorCorrectionLevel: "h",
        color: {
          dark: "#000000",
          light: "#0000",
        },
      })
        .then((dataURI) => {
          resolve(dataURI);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    } else {
      return address;
    }
  });
}

export default QrCode;
```

Comment: In React, the address is a good example of something that works well as a prop: `<QrCode address="..the url in the qr code.." />` for example. With usage like this, it makes it easier to follow through that state inside App.js can then directly set that address prop. QrCode.js itself can then update the image on mount/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js is the parent component and QrCode.js is the child component. From parent to child you can pass by props directly.

In App.js, create a state object and update it on receiving fetch response. React re-renders component and its children whenever state object changes.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import QrCode from "../qrCode/qrCode";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  this.state = { qrCodeImage: null};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <QrCode qrCodeImage={this.state.qrCodeImage} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getSessionID() {
    fetch("/getSessionID")
      .then((res) => {
        // code here to update the qr code in the instance of QrCode
        // QrCode.updateQrCode("test")
      })
      .then((data) => this.setState({ qrCodeImage:data }));
  }
}

export default App;
```

QrCode.js

```
updateQrCode = () => {
    this.setState({
      qrCode: {
        address: "asdf",
        image: this.props.qrCodeImage,
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this by calling the updateQrCode Method rather than creating a state member?

Comment: But why would you like to do this? As the image received event happened in Parent - App.js class hence updating it's state will rerender Child - QrCode. Now your updateQrCode is updating it's state and hence even if you call updateQrCode on receiving image at App.js, the child QrCode component will be rerendered, but first approach is standard approach in React.

Comment: I'm new to react, but I feel like it will get messy / lots of extra code if App.js has to have a copy of the state of all its children it wants to keep updated

Comment: You can also move the `getSessionId` method to QrCode.js if it has nothing to do with App.js.